# Is there missing a comma in this sentence? "When I was at the Academy I had the pick of models, but now I can never seem to hang on to them. "

Tags: grammar, punctuation

Obviously, this is a compound-complex sentence. Is there missing a comma between the first two clauses in this sentence?

Orignial: "When I was at the Academy I had the pick of models, but now I can never seem to hang on to them. "

Changed: "When I was at the Academy, I had the pick of models, but now I can never seem to hang on to them. "

Comment: A comma is unnecessary, but correct, in that position. Think of it as optional. The original two clauses make a complete sentence in which the comma is also optional; I think the comma detracts from the meaning of the longer sentence.

Answer (score 1):

"When I was at the Academy" is an [adverbial clause.](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/adverbial_clauses.htm) When we put adverbial clauses at the start of a sentence, we normally put a comma between the adverbial clause and the main sentence. The longer or more complex the adverbial clause, the more important the comma.

You can use a comma after a leading single word adverb, but it is definitely not necessary:

> Tomorrow, we will got shopping.
> Tomorrow we will go shopping.

Comment: HI JavaLatte. What if the sentence is like this: "When I was at the Academy, I had the pick of models." Can the comma be dropped?

Comment: @DenAllan The adverbial clause in your sentence is the same, and that's the deciding factor on whether a comma is necessary. If you simplified the adverbial clause "That year I had the pick of models..." then the comma is less important. The complexity of the main clause doesn't affect it.

Comment: So it is grammatically correct without the comma. On the other hand, I guess it has to do with style regarding if it is necessary. "When I was at the Academy I had the pick of models." It looks strange to me without comma.